# MS Teams Tab - file download on Android and iOS clients

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way how to force MS Teams native client for iOS and Android to download a file from a custom Teams tab?
Currently it only tries to preview the file content which is useless.

I'm trying to download a file using a simple anchor link rendered within my Tab/web page that is displayed in MS Teams client. This works for all of the Teams desktop clients (native or web) as well as for detached tab (tab opened in a browser app e.g. Chrome) on iOS and Android platforms.

This is the Tab web app code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>MS Teams test page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="/download" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
</body>

</html>
```

With Express server as backend serving file this way:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
 
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get("/download", (req, res) => {
    res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=archive.zip");
    res.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    res.sendFile("AuthTest.zip", {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'dl'),
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
          'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
          'x-sent': true
        }
      });
});
 
app.listen(80)
```

I also tested download using an iFrame element created via jQuery that targeted the download URL with the same result - iFrame showing a content preview instead of downloading it.

There's similar problem on Android as well where the app will open web browser app instead of downloading the file within the MS Teams app.

Comment: we are checking it get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Currently when you give target and download a file will work on the desktop/web browser in teams , but it will not work on the mobile clients. This is by design. You need to upload the file to teams first and then download the file from files tab in mobile clients. Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Bots/AttachmentsBot.cs) which shown how to download an inline image in teams.

Comment: The sample refers to bot framework. Is it possible to download a file from teams without bot framework?

Comment: Is there now a solution to this problem? I have an angular spa  inside a teams tab. On android my teams tab crashs, if I trie to download a file.